# container wont display padding

Tags: css, padding

My .container won't display padding. I have tried multiple methods and it won't pad.

CSS:

```
nav{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 70vh;
}

ul{
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.container{
    border-top: solid;
    border-right: solid;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-color: green;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 97vw;
    height: 70vh;
}
```

HTML:

```
<article>
<nav>
<ul style="list-style-type:none;">
<li><strike>home</strike></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.php">portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="portfolio.php">dsdfsdfs</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<div class="container"></div>
</article>
```

No matter what value I set the padding-left to, the padding always remains the same.

Comment: your padding works but it is pad from the article. SO you have to place your div position correctly.

Comment: Your padding is OK, please let me know what do you want the result to be an I will help you

Comment: I'm looking to achive a nav that's joined to the container, and that the container doesn't wrap beneath the nav

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/98mazpaz/4/)

**Updated CSS:**

```
nav{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: green;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 70vh;
}

ul{
    padding:0px;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.container{
    border-top: solid;
    border-right: solid;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-color: green;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 75vw;
    height: 70vh;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}
```